# sorting an array related to a string array in c

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to sort a string related to an array based on the values of the array, for some reason the sorting part inst working.. when i try to sort the elements related to each other and print them for some reason the print comes out incredibly randomly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int sorting(char name[][10],double average[],int size);

int main()
{
    double sales1[10],sales2[10],sales3[10],average[10],test,totalm=0,totalfm=0,test2;          
int i=0,j;
char name[10][10],gender[10];
printf("Please input the name, the gender, and the sales for the\nfirst three months followed by a spacebar after each element\n");
scanf("%s %c %lf %lf %lf",&name[0],&gender[0],&sales1[0],&sales2[0],&sales3[0]);
average[i]=(sales1[i]+sales2[i]+sales3[i])/3;
while(strcmp(name[i],"enough")!=0)
{
     i++;
     printf("Please input the name, the gender, and the sales for the\nfirst three months followed by a spacebar after each element\n");
     scanf("%s %c %lf %lf %lf",&name[i],&gender[i],&sales1[i],&sales2[i],&sales3[i]);
     average[i]=(sales1[i]+sales2[i]+sales3[i])/3;
}
sorting(name,average,i);
j=i;
while(i>=0)
 {
    if(gender[i]=='m')
      totalm=totalm+average[i];
    else
      totalfm=totalfm+average[i];
    i--;
 }
   while(j>=0)
    {
    test2=strcmp(name[j],"enough");
    if(test2!=0)
      printf("%s\t%f\n",name[j],average[j]);
      j--;
      }
      printf("total male sales are %f\n",totalm);
      printf("total female sales are %f\n",totalfm);


  }
 int sorting(char name[][10],double average[], int size)
 {
int i=0;
double temp;
char ntemp[20][20];
while(i<=size)
 {
     if(average[i+1]>average[i])
      {
          temp=average[i];
          strcpy(ntemp[i],name[i]);
          average[i]=average[i+1];
          strcpy(name[i],name[i+1]);
          average[i+1]=temp;
          strcpy(name[i+1],ntemp[i]);
      }
    i++;
 }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Please don't write code like that. You must respect your peers and writing such an unreadable code is not precisely that. Use more white space and cleaner declarations.

Comment: `j=i;
while(i>=0)
 {
    if(gender[i]=='m')` : note last valid data index is `i - 1`

Comment: `while(i<=size)
 {
     if(average[i+1]>average[i])` : out of bounds.

Comment: Why have `char ntemp[20][20];`? One temp varable should be enough! And why do you "know" here it is 20 but in the argument passing the first dimension is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thisn't a valid sort. You bubble one element to its proper position. Lookup bubble sort: it has two loops. The inner loop moves the current element, the outer loop loops over all remaining, unsorted elements.

See also the other comments to your posting for more bugs.

Comment: One thing though, im facing another problem with the female/male total... can you see the flaw?

Answer (score 1):

i think the sorting you have applied seems to be wrong on very first condition of your sorting function

```
while(i<=size)
 {
     if(average[i+1]>average[i])
      {
          temp=average[i];
```

assume the condition when i is equals to size then the average[i+1] will be point to nothing on you can say zero that value, which you don't set.
so try to correct this code

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   for(k=0;k<n-i-1;k++)
    {
     if(a[k]>a[k+1])
      {
       temp=a[k];
       a[k]=a[k+1];
       a[k+1]=temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

this is the bubble sort where you always iterate one less than the last pass.
for more [see here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/2016/03/c-program-to-implement-bubble-sort.html)